# How do you print user input in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to print the user input? Everytime I click on the submit button, it just redirects me to a blank page. Here's the code:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>NameTest</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="PayslipServlet" method="get">

        Last name:    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br/>
        First name:   <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br/>
        Middle name:  <input type="text" name="mname" id ="mname"><br/>
        Name:<script>document.write(document.getElementById('fname').value+" "+document.getElementById('mname').value+""+document.getElementById('lname').value);</script>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Print it how? Print it where? Print it when? Have a look at other questions... we need a lot more info in order to help you without guessing

Comment: Print it in the same html page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript/HTML: How to display user input into html body?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17179049/javascript-html-how-to-display-user-input-into-html-body)

Answer (score 7):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but try this:

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/t8zo7L5e/)

```html
        <form action="PayslipServlet" method="get">
          Last name:    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br/>
          First name:   <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br/>
          Middle name:  <input type="text" name="mname" id ="mname"><br/>
          Name: <span id="result"></span>
          <br>
          <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="pr()">
        </form>

        <script>
          function pr() {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById('fname').value + " " + document.getElementById('mname').value + " " + document.getElementById('lname').value;
          }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use submit, if you want to stay on the current page. Client side printing can be easily achieved by using a button with a click listener.

```js
window.writeValues = function(form) {
  var fname = form.fname.value;
  var mname = form.mname.value;
  var lname = form.lname.value;

  document.getElementById('fullname').innerHTML = fname + ' ' + mname + ' ' + lname;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<form action="PayslipServlet" method="get">
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br/>
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br/>
  Middle name: <input type="text" name="mname" id="mname"><br/>
  Name: <span id="fullname"></span><br />
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="writeValues(form)">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <html>
<head>
    <title>NameTest</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="PayslipServlet" method="get">
        <div ng-app="">
        Last name:    <input type="text" name="lname" ng-model="lname" id="lname"><br/>
        First name:   <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="fname" id="fname"><br/>
        Middle name:  <input type="text" name="mname" ng-model="mname" id ="mname"><br/>
        full Name: {{lname}}&nbsp;{{fname}}&nbsp;{{mname}}<br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

print easily with angularjs instead of javascript

Comment: It doesn't seem he's interested in using a framework as he didn't specify any one, so you should assume vanilla javascript

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should't be using a form if you just want to print your user input, as per my understanding of your question I can suggest some code like these, BTW there some really good Javascript libraries that do what you want to do it without any troubles, like knockout.

## Here it goes, Click on run Code Snippet, it works here

```js
var el = document.getElementById("showName");
el.addEventListener("click", formatName, false);

function formatName () {
  var name = document.getElementById('fname').value;
  var mname = document.getElementById('mname').value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById('lname').value;

  document.getElementById('fullName').innerHTML = name + " " + mname + " " + lastname; 
}
```

```html
<form action="PayslipServlet" method="get">
  Last name:    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br/>
  First name:   <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br/>
  Middle name:  <input type="text" name="mname" id ="mname"><br/>
  Name: <span id="fullName"></span>
  <input id="showName" type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.writeValues = function(form) {
  var fname = form.fname.value;
  var mname = form.mname.value;
  var lname = form.lname.value;

  document.getElementById('fullname').innerHTML = fname + ' ' + mname + ' ' + lname;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<form action="PayslipServlet" method="get">
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"><br/>
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"><br/>
  Middle name: <input type="text" name="mname" id="mname"><br/>
  Name: <span id="fullname"></span><br />
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="writeValues(form)">
</form>
```